# How to create Union or Pick type from an interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type for my Redux store object something along the lines of:

```
 interface StoreState {
    state1: State1Type;
    state2: State2Type;
    state3: {
      state3a: State3aType;
    };
  }
```

I'd like to create a new type based on StoreState that'd let me pick from any of the types in StoreState as if were a union: `NewType: State1Type | State2Type | State3aType`

From what I've read it looks like the answer might be in using mapped types, but I can't work out how to implement this.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEYAq5oF4oHI6JXUhwChRJYEkAmIrXfGu086RiAZnjqmzys7cMpEiQCWAOyQAnAGbwAxm2AB7aRHZQA3iSh6oAZwHIAXJQJoMAbl36jBamfa1rtvfaQczO-b8MCuJwChSBtfAF8bcNEAegAqON04qABNFQBXKAV4CSh0g2hgAAsxAzzgMQAbMVAoUqgQDOk6qQg5RWh62UrEJJiyDCgANXhK9IgDAB5UAD5eKFQAbQBrCEbZBYBdWISkqABJXMb05uyChozDIozKgBMoeFv7-YAxLJUJW5qxD4AaKAARhBsvlOq12ko6mUJCpgFBur0oHF+qwoAAlCbpSpw7A+fSLAAKLSgq3WlDUGgEmzMRIgAA8kJ8yjgPJwcFAAPzk9TsRYsgI4TZ81lcQVQIIU3kE7bhFZrFQbOCSqlAA 
Are you ok with such solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract values' types recursively:

```
interface StoreState {
    state1: '1';
    state2: '2';
    state3: {
        state3a: '3';
    };
}

type ValuesDeep<T, V = T[keyof T]> = V extends object ? ValuesDeep<V> : V

type NewType = ValuesDeep<StoreState>; // "1" | "2" | "3"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPZQuulkDeAUMqcgM5h4QCMAXMgOQ2MDcJZl1ATA492w6kukAMwNiZKRSpi4fUYKkBfdsqJEwATwAOKAGpwANgFcI5ACIQIOgDwAVADTJ9yALzJ7AbQDWELRgwngC6AHzuLsgQAB6QIAAm5MgYAEYAVhAIYMgA-C7GZpbWdvrhDPoa2nrIAHIQAO72uigehqbmVja26Fg4shChrMgA9MPIAEQ048gAPhPc03PjouNAA)

Comment: This solution is a way better than mine!

Comment: This solution is really clever, however I do get this error whilst implementing it: "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite."

Comment: @Antfish do you use the latest version of typescript? How many nested levels do you have in type you're working with?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Version in my webpack is: "typescript": "^3.6.3",

Only need to go one level deep currently (like state3a in my example)